# SQL | Вытянуть только тех пациентов у кого не было приёма после 2019 года

Tags: sql

Есть таблицы [Patient], [Schedule], [SchedulePatient].
Используя такой запрос я хотел вытащить пациентов([Patient]) у которых не было приёма ([Schedule],[SchedulePatient]) после определённого года используя этот запрос:

```
SELECT   Patient.PatientID, Patient.PatientName, Patient.PatientPersonalNumber, Schedule.ScheduleID, Schedule.ScheduleName,Schedule.ScheduleStatusRef, Schedule.ScheduleEndTime, SchedulePatient.ScheduleRef, SchedulePatient.PatientRef
FROM     Patient INNER  JOIN
                  SchedulePatient ON Patient.PatientID = SchedulePatient.PatientRef  INNER JOIN
                  Schedule ON SchedulePatient.ScheduleRef = Schedule.ScheduleID where ScheduleEndTime < '2019-01-01'
```

Есть колонки ScheduleStartTime и ScheduleEndTime соответственно начало и конец приёма. Данные хранят в таком виде 2016-07-05 17:30:00.000. Как правильно построить условия что бы вытащить только пациентов которые ходили на приём до 2019 года?

Comment: как вариант можно так `group by ... having max(d) <= '2018-12-31'` )

Comment: либо выбрать пациентов которые ходили `LEFT JOIN (select distinct id ... WHERE x >= '2019-01-01') as x` и выкинуть их `where x.id is null`

Comment: либо комбинированный вариант `INNER  JOIN (select patientRed ... group by patientRef having max(d) <= '2020-12-31' ) as x ON (x.patientRef = patientID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        Patient.PatientID, 
        Patient.PatientName, 
        Patient.PatientPersonalNumber
FROM 
       Patient 
       LEFT JOIN SchedulePatient 
           INNER JOIN Schedule 
               ON SchedulePatient.ScheduleRef = Schedule.ScheduleID 
                 AND Schedule.ScheduleEndTime >= '2019-01-01'
          ON Patient.PatientID = SchedulePatient.PatientRef 
       INNER JOIN SchedulePatient AS SchedulePatient1
           INNER JOIN Schedule AS Schedule1 
               ON SchedulePatient1.ScheduleRef = Schedule1.ScheduleID 
                 AND Schedule1.ScheduleEndTime < '2019-01-01'
          ON Patient.PatientID = SchedulePatient1.PatientRef 
where 
    SchedulePatient.SchedulePatientID IS NULL
```